# Saving file in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, save

I am trying to save a file that I edit in zend. In fact that is document.xml, a part of .docx ducument. I take a docx file, extract document.xml, do some changes in the content and want to show pop up dialogue box to save new file or open it.
The result is almost ok, but instead of zip pack I receive a text file with zip extension where in content I can find in fact zipped  files but within view/layout content.
My code is like below:

```
$zip = New ZipArchive();
   $newReportFilename = "Report_" . date('Y-m-d_H-i-s') . ".docx";
   $dir = getcwd();
   $templateLocation = "$dir\\report_template.docx";
   $tempFile = "$dir\\$newReportFilename";
       copy($templateLocation,$tempFile);

$zip->open($tempFile);
$fp = $zip->getStream("word/document.xml");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $fileContent .= fread($fp, 2);
    }

fclose($fp);   
$fileContent = "... some xml content ...";

$zip->addFromString("word/document.xml", $fileContent);
$zip->close()

header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize("$dir\\$newReportFilename"));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"Reportfile.zip\"");
readfile("$dir\\$newReportFilename");
```

and something like this I receive in output file:

```
... 
<form id="createReport" name="createReport" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" action=""><dl class="zend_form">
<dt id="runId-label"><label for="runId" class="optional">Run ID</label></dt>
<dd id="runId-element">
<input type="text" name="runId" id="runId" value="81"></dd>
<dt id="submit-label">&#160;</dt><dd id="submit-element">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Dalej"></dd></dl></form>okPK¶     ! 8+-?¦  s   [Content_Types].xml ó(                                                                                         ¦V-n¦0+F?+¥éó¦£C¦$@¦¤á+ò-û/Éd-¦v,¡X(YGF"@vf+3+-=~oM±1injvS-XNzÑ¦ªf++-»¼H(£¦;¿++_}¦¦\ñé¬]¬+1|p<+-Xæ*+-¢+G+Énpå! ë=¦+GÄKnûÿ1+j·HóVP<ëê¤-¤±Q±+{t!U¦èn]]ª«Ö-h)Éä=gº+HK¯¦Zé=rgë¬-p!z )--¼¬zF/Ü»û?á§;â+-=id+-hw§¬7=+në=â¦£ßk¢¢öƒ¤+¦V8-nf+&éIgE+¥Y§Uv¢¦:ñæ>ì¢=+¯ï&˜ì+++p+fN/Op;¦@ñt||+zFI¤fÄ+w+ô(a+L=vBô@~=Eº|^mS9VáJv 5(+üê¶Ç+-  
y8°²-âxs)±-I~  
...
```

Some experiments with text files only gave me the same result which is, inside a file I got I see view/layout content with some text given by me.
The whole editing and zipping works fine when I just save the file in a disk, but I would like the user to decide what to do with this by save as dialogue box.

Do you know how to get rid of this view/layout content?
And get the file only.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was quite obvious. Renderer and layout need to be disabled.

```
// Both layout and view renderer should be disabled
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer')->setNoRender(true);
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->disableLayout();
```